# How can I define the function bill(L, "Costco") in Python to sum up the amounts in this list?

Tags: python

```
L = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500' ]
```

I wrote this code but I can´t change the amounts from str() to int().

```
a = L[0].split()
b = L[1].split()
c = L[2].split()
d = L[3].split()
bill = np.array([a,b,c,d])
bill
```

Comment: Split returns an array of strings like `["Netflix", "100"]`, so you need to get the second part of each array, which is the number, and convert it to int. Something like `int(L[0].split()[0])` should work. Also you may not need numpy to sum up some small numbers, python has a function called sum() itself which works well with cases like your example.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this if you want to use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re
L = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500' ]
sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", "".join(L))))
```

**Output:**

```
1300
```

**Update:**

As you wanted to filter for values "Costco" and then compute sum, you could use this:

```
L = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500' ]
filter = [i for i in L if 'Costco' in i] 
sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", "".join(filter))))
```

**Output:**

```
700
```

Comment: Ah yes, use regex to get the number when it's clearly space separated

Comment: And if I just want to sum for example Costco?

Comment: Are you asking what would be the sum when `L=['Costco']` ? If yes, it would be `0` and when `L=['Costco 500']`, in that case sum would be `500`

Comment: And how can I do `function(L,'Costco')` to get `700`

Comment: So in that case, does your input List L have 700 in it ?

Comment: No but in the list there is two elements  `"Costco 500", "Costco 200"`. I just want to sum those elements not the whole list.

Comment: You can refer the `update section` in my answer for `"Costco 500", "Costco 200"` @Rota

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this?

```
L = ["Netflix 100", "Costco 200", "Blockbuster 50"]

bill = np.array([int(string.split()[1]) for string in L])
```

And to sum up simply use `sum`:

```
sum([int(string.split()[1]) for string in L])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code -

```
L = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500' ]
a = int(L[0][-3:])
b = int(L[1][-3:])
c = int(L[2][-3:])
d = int(L[3][-3:])
bill = np.array([a,b,c,d])
print(bill)
#if you want more flexibility, then use regular expressions to retrieve the values 
#from last
```

I will use the following code in case of 200 items -

```
lst = []
for i in range(len(L)):
    lst.append(int(L[i][-3:]))
bill = np.array(lst)
print(bill)
```

Hope that the edit is useful for you though it not one of those beautiful one lines.

Comment: imagine when you have 200 items in L

Comment: You can use the following

Comment: `bill = np.array([int(e[-3:]) for e in L])`

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, use regex to get the number when it's clearly space separated

```
L = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500']
numbers = [element.split()[1] for element in L] # .split() is same as .split(' '), 'Netflix 100' -> ['Netflix', '100']
integers = [int(number) for number in numbers]
print (sum(integers))

# One liner
print (sum(int(e.split()[1]) for e in L))

# Another one liner
print (sum(map(lambda e: int(e.split()[1]), L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data into a pandas series and then convert it into a dataframe with one column containing the company name and another containing the value. You can then use the pandas functions to generate the reports.

Load the data into a pandas series

```
% ipython
Python 3.10.6 (main, Oct 24 2022, 16:07:47) [GCC 11.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.6.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 
import pandas as pd
strings = ['Netflix 100' , 'Costco 200' , 'Walmart 500', 'Costco 500' ]
s = pd.Series(strings)
print(s)
0    Netflix 100
1     Costco 200
2    Walmart 500
3     Costco 500
dtype: object
```

Create a dataframe with one column containing the company name and another containing the value

```
In [2]: 
df = s.str.split(expand=True)
print(df)
         0    1
0  Netflix  100
1   Costco  200
2  Walmart  500
3   Costco  500
```

Name the columns and convert the second column into floats.

```
In [3]: 
df.columns = ['company', 'value']
df['value'] = df['value'].astype('float')
print(df)
   company  value
0  Netflix  100.0
1   Costco  200.0
2  Walmart  500.0
3   Costco  500.0
```

To report the total sum of values:

```
In [4]: 
df['value'].sum()
Out[4]: 
1300.0
```

To group / break it down by the company:

```
In [5]: 
df.groupby(['company'])['value'].sum().reset_index()
Out[5]: 
   company  value
0   Costco  700.0
1  Netflix  100.0
2  Walmart  500.0
```